# Running a repository on Github

Tags: github, compilation, execute

How do I write a code on GitHub and after writing how do I run or execute the code.

I tried writing a new file on GitHub and I wanted to run or execute it but I did not know how to do it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I want to know how to run a code after writing it on GitHub. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Github is not a place where you can run code. On the website, you can only write code, as you did, but if you want to actually run it you have to do it locally on your computer.